# How many groups contain only zeros and what is the average number of observations in these groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have data as below

```
library(dplyr)

DF<-data.frame(ID=c(seq(1,14, by = 1)),
               C1=c(9.1,0,9,9.2,9.1,0,0,9.3,9.1,9.0,0,0,0,0) ,
               grp = c(1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6)
)
```

I want to make a statement (summary) with the following information:

- how many groups containing zeros are there (in this case there are 3 such groups: 2, 4, 6)
- how many rows does the "longest" null group have (in this case, the longest null group is group 6 and has 4 rows)
- what is the average length of the null groups (group 2 has one row, group 4 has two rows and group 6 has four rows - (1+2+4)/3 = 2.333

**EDIT:**
I would like to extend my question

```
library(dplyr)

DF<-data.frame(ID=c(seq(1,14, by = 1)),
               C1=c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,3,3,3,0,0,0,0) ,
               grp = c(1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6)
)
```

The solution given by @Andre Wildberg is very good. I would like to extend the issue and get a summary like below:

```
  C1.value    Grps longest     Mean
1        0       3       4 2.333333
2        1       2       3 2.0
3        3       1       3 3.0
```

I tried this solution

```
 DF %>% 
  group_by(C1, grp) %>% 
  summarize(Grps = cur_group_id(), N = n()) %>% 
  summarize(Grps = max(Grps), longest = max(N), Mean = mean(N))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
     C1  Grps longest  Mean
  <dbl> <int>   <int> <dbl>
1     0     3       4  2.33
2     1     5       3  2   
3     3     6       3  3
```

The Grps column is not as expected

I got as below, although it's not very elegant solution

```
DF %>% 
  group_by(C1, grp) %>% 
  summarize(Grps = cur_group_id(), N = n()) %>% 
  summarize(Grps = max(Grps), longest = max(N), Mean = mean(N)) %>% 
  mutate (
    Grps.1 = Grps - lag (Grps),
    Grps.1 = if_else (is.na(Grps.1), Grps, Grps.1)
  )
```

Comment: Please share the code you ask to be examined for improvement.

Comment: Hey @GrBa, youre likely getting negative votes because you don’t appear to have attempted anything (asking people to do your work for you with little effort will get some quick downvotes) and also because stack overflow only encourages one question per post. It’s also unclear what your desired output would be. You could improve the question by describing your desired output, your current code attempting to achieve it, and why it didn’t work. Good luck!

Comment: @jpsmith Thank you for your comment - it clarifies a lot and I will be able to prepare my questions better

Comment: @GrBa I think its ok to ask another question since after the edit the title doesn't fit anymore. You're not searching for zeros but for some group summary based on a value. You can roll back your changes to make the original question valid again and put your changes in another question, possibly referencing this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's no desired output yet here's a way it could look like. Using `near` for floating point comparison.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  filter(near(C1, 0)) %>% 
  summarize(Grps = cur_group_id(), N = n(), .by = grp) %>% 
  summarize(Grps = max(Grps), longest = max(N), Mean = mean(N))
  Grps longest     Mean
1    3       4 2.333333
```

Note: *"how many groups containing zeros are there"* differs somewhat from what the title would suggest (*"only zeros"*). So if it should be groups with only zeros, change the first `filter` step to `filter(all(near(C1, 0)), .by = grp)`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time and sharing your knowledge. I appreciate it very much.
If C1 contained only the values 0,1,3, it may suggest how to rewrite your answer so that I get three lines in the summary. I hope that's understandable. If not, should I ask a new question?

Comment: @GrBa No worries, glad I could help. If you just want a different expected output you can construct an expected output in the same way you provided your data frame `DF` and then add it to your question through EDIT. I'd suggest doing that with the old data in mind to not invalidate other answers.  If you're changing `DF` significantly and trying to solve a different problem you definitely might want to consider asking a new question.

Comment: I edited the question as per your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

##### How many groups containing zeros are there?

```
summarise(DF, n = any(C1 == 0), .by = grp) |> 
  pull(n) |> 
  sum() # [1] 3
```

##### How many rows does the longest group of zeros have?

```
z <- DF |>
  mutate(zeros = C1 == 0 & lag(C1, default = 1) != 0, .by= grp) |>
  mutate(zeros = cumsum(zeros)) |> 
  filter(C1 == 0) |> 
  summarise(n = length(zeros), .by = c(grp, zeros))

max(z$n) # [1] 4
```

##### What is the average length of the groups of zeroes?

```
mean(z$n) # [1] 2.333333
```

The statement you will have to write for yourself! Though you could use glue and have the values inserted automatically :-)

Answer (score 1):

for good measure, here's a base R variant:

```
DF |>
  subset(C1 == 0) |>
  (\(x) with(x, table(grp)))() |>
  (\(tbl) list(group_count = length(tbl),
               max_length = max(tbl),
               group_with_most_zeros = names(tbl)[which.max(tbl)])
  )() 

$group_count
[1] 3

$max_length
[1] 4

$group_with_most_zeros
[1] "6"
```