# groups based on values and a summary with basic information about the groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have data

```
library(dplyr)

DF<-data.frame(ID=c(seq(1,14, by = 1)),
               C1=c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,3,3,3,0,0,0,0) ,
               grp = c(1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6)
)
```

The solution given by @Andre Wildberg is very good ([How many groups contain only zeros and what is the average number of observations in these groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76939513/how-many-groups-contain-only-zeros-and-what-is-the-average-number-of-observation?noredirect=1#comment135636249_76939513)).

I would like to extend the issue and get a summary like below:

```
  C1.value    Grps longest     Mean
1        0       3       4 2.333333
2        1       2       3 2.0
3        3       1       3 3.0
```

I tried this solution

```
 DF %>% 
  group_by(C1, grp) %>% 
  summarize(Grps = cur_group_id(), N = n()) %>% 
  summarize(Grps = max(Grps), longest = max(N), Mean = mean(N))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
     C1  Grps longest  Mean
  <dbl> <int>   <int> <dbl>
1     0     3       4  2.33
2     1     5       3  2   
3     3     6       3  3
```

The Grps column is not as expected

I got as below, although it's not very elegant solution

```
DF %>% 
  group_by(C1, grp) %>% 
  summarize(Grps = cur_group_id(), N = n()) %>% 
  summarize(Grps = max(Grps), longest = max(N), Mean = mean(N)) %>% 
  mutate (
    Grps.1 = Grps - lag (Grps),
    Grps.1 = if_else (is.na(Grps.1), Grps, Grps.1)
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `group_modify` to summarize each `C1` group separately instead of summarizing by both `C1` and `grp`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

DF |>
  group_by(C1) |>
  group_modify(~
    .x |>
      summarise(N = n(), .by = grp) |>
      summarise(
        Grps = n(), longest = max(N), Mean = mean(N)
      )) |>
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>      C1  Grps longest  Mean
#>   <dbl> <int>   <int> <dbl>
#> 1     0     3       4  2.33
#> 2     1     2       3  2   
#> 3     3     1       3  3
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It helps in this particular case, but adds to my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

another approach:

```
library(dplyr)

DF |>
reframe(C1_count = table(C1), .by = c(grp, C1))|>
summarize(Grps = length(grp),
          longest = max(C1_count),
          Mean = mean(C1_count),
          .by = C1) |>
arrange(C1) |>
rename(C1.value = C1)
```

output:

```
  C1.value Grps longest     Mean
1        0    3       4 2.333333
2        1    2       3 2.000000
3        3    1       3 3.000000
```